# How to change active tab background color as selected tab without click?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Change tab background-color when clicked it's works fine but I have the first tab active I want to make the color of it same as the selected tab and remove the color of it when another tab selected

here http://jsfiddle.net/zjjpocv6/541/

```js
$(function() {
    $('#navigation li').click(function() {
            $('#navigation li').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        
    });
});
```

```css
.selected{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="navigation">
        <li role="presentation" class="active" >
            <a href="#supervisorInfo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#studentsInfo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#reportSummary" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
        </li>

        <li class="float-right">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="float-right btn btn-primary" />

        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS

```
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus{
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply give the initially active tab the `selected` class:

```
<li role="presentation" class="active selected" >
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('#navigation li').click(function() {
            $('#navigation li').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        
    });
});
```

```css
.selected{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="navigation">
        <li role="presentation" class="active selected" >
            <a href="#supervisorInfo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#studentsInfo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#reportSummary" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
        </li>

        <li class="float-right">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="float-right btn btn-primary" />

        </li>
    </ul>
```